# How to sniff internet connection from mobile application?

Tags: iphone, fiddler, sniffing

Sometimes if we uses web application from our computer we can sniff the data. We can use iehttpheader for ie. We can use livehttpheader for firefox. Or we can use fidler.

But what about if we use mobile phone?

Is there a way to force all internet traffic to go through our computer first, and then catch that with fiddler?

I tried to use bluestack to run android application but fiddler shows nothing.

A friend of mine try to set it's android tablet to use my computer as proxy. This approach works for many applications but doesn't work for another.

Comment: Typically, pointing the mobile device's proxy settings at your PC is sufficient to capture its traffic. The BlueStack desktop emulator has a (commonly complained about) bug where it doesn't use the system's proxy setting properly. Complain to them and perhaps they'll fix it some day.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wifi card on your machine that you can put in master mode, you can share the connection from your machine to your phone and then you can use one of your tools (you can try wireshark as well) to capture the traffic from your phone.

Comment: That's a hard way to do it.